# Retrieve ancestor element with a certain data attribute

Tags: javascript, html

How can I retrieve an ancestor element with a certain data attribute by clicking one of its children elements?

I need to get the `data-cell` attribute when clicking either a `<span>` or a `<div>`. I tried to use `node.parentElement`, but when I click a span it returns me the div, and it's clear.

Is there something like `node.parentElement.dataset.dataCell` to get what I need?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="out" data-cell="3-2-2015">
     <div>
        <span> Number one </span>
        <span> Number two </span>
        <span> Number three </span>
     </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What did you try? *`node.parentElement.dataset.dataCell`* Did this work?

Comment: @Jonathan From a child to a parent using querySelectorAll?

Comment: @Mouser
No, console.log returns "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", function(e){
         var element = e.target;
         var found = false;
         if (element.tagName != "TABLE")
         {
             while(element && element.parentElement && element.tagName != "TABLE")
             {
                 if (element.hasAttribute("data-cell") )
                 {
                     found = element.getAttribute("data-cell");
                     break; //stop the loop;
                 }
                 element = element.parentElement;
             }
         }
      
         alert(found);
    });
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="out" data-cell="3-2-2015">
     <div>
        <span> Number one </span>
        <span> Number two </span>
        <span> Number three </span>
     </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="out" >
     <div>
        <span> Number one </span>
        <span> Number two </span>
        <span> Number three </span>
     </div>
  </td>
 </tr>  
  
</table>
```

This will do it:

Uses a while loop to iterate back up DOM tree using `parentElement`. If the attribute `data-cell` is found return the element and break the loop if not then return `false`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Alert window returns: [object HTML TableCellElement]

Comment: So what ? It makes sense since "found" is an HTML Object.

Comment: Works like a charm. In the if in the loop add `.getAttribute("data-cell")` after element.

Comment: @Mouser Nothing's changed.
Same message in Alert window.

Comment: @chikamtsu But I want to retrieve the exact td instead.

Comment: @alexandrbelov updated it. Was hoping you figured to do that out by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="out" data-cell="3-2-2015">
            <div class="div clicker">
                <span class="span clicker"> Number one </span>
                <span class="span clicker"> Number two </span>
                <span class="span clicker"> Number three </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// generic functions
window.getAncestorWithAttribute = function(elem,attr) {
    elem = elem.parentNode;
    while (elem) {
        if (elem.hasAttribute(attr))
            return elem;
        elem = elem.parentNode;
    } // end while
    return null;
}; // end getAncestorWithAttribute()

// event handlers
window.mainClickCallback = function(ev) { alert(getAncestorWithAttribute(ev.target,'data-cell')); ev.stopPropagation(); };

// attach event handlers to target elements
Array.forEach(document.getElementsByClassName('clicker'), function(elem) { elem.addEventListener('click', mainClickCallback ); } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8fba8jg/4/

Comment: It isn't working.
I don't know, may be my question is unclear. But what I need, is to get td (which is supposed to be found by its data attribute) when clicking either div or span elements.

Comment: See updated answer. Let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", function(e){
         var element = e.target;
         var found = false;
         if (element.tagName != "TABLE")
         {
             while(element && element.parentElement && element.tagName != "TABLE")
             {
                 if (element.hasAttribute("data-cell") )
                 {
                     found = element.getAttribute("data-cell");
                     break; //stop the loop;
                 }
                 element = element.parentElement;
             }
         }
      
         alert(found);
    });
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="out" data-cell="3-2-2015">
     <div>
        <span> Number one </span>
        <span> Number two </span>
        <span> Number three </span>
     </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="out" >
     <div>
        <span> Number one </span>
        <span> Number two </span>
        <span> Number three </span>
     </div>
  </td>
 </tr>  
  
</table>
```